# analogue $ (document). click (function (e) without reference of event

Tags: jquery

I need to close some popup, click-through beyond. 
For this I use the following code:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (target.is('div.date_body') || target.is('div.date_header') || target.is('div.date_header button') || target.parents('.popuplayout').length) 
        return;

    $(document).unbind('click', arguments.callee);
    scope.callFadeOut();
    scope.accept();
});
```

But now, it was necessary to abandon the argument e passed. 
Perhaps someone can suggest a way to implement it?

Comment: what do you mean by `it was necessary to abandon the argument e passed`?

Comment: I meant that it was necessary to realize such functionality without using the argument "e". Without using the event object.

Comment: Honestly still vague to me. Are you just after a solution which doesn't use `e`? If so why?

Comment: Right, need a solution which doesn't use e. Reason why there was such a need, is the architectural features of the application.

Comment: What feature could possibly forbid such access? You simply cannot access the `event target` without accessing the event `object`, that's what the `event` object is for. Any other solution would require binding to the elements targeted and thus making this code obsolete.

Comment: Can you give an example or a link to the sample solution? I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is a code that should more or less do the same, also using `event` is probably the best call even Angular return the `event` object.

http://jsfiddle.net/6T4Rn/

Click once to see `do nothing`, note that it is triggered multiple times due to event propagation and well you need to access `event` to stop that.

If you remove the `<div class="popup_layout"></div>`, run the jsfiddle and click it will output `do stuff` here only once as the we unbind the handler.

HTML - generated by guess based on your JS

```
<div>
    <div class="date_header">
        <button>Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="date_body"></div>
    <div class="popup_layout"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
// Basically target all elements but not the one we want to ignore
var selector = "*:not(.date_header, .date_header button,.date_body)";

$(selector).on("click", function() {

    // the popup layout check
    if ($(".popup_layout").size()) {
        console.log("do nothing");
        return;
    }

    $(selector).unbind("click");

    // your scope stuff here
    console.log("do stuff");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is exactly what I need. Once again, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, for did not do this immediately.